Are there any verbs with a particle such as 'ab' where the basic infinitive does not exist?
I thought I had found one in 'abflauen' but 'flauen' was apparently used at one time and so it is one of many which have lost their simple version over time. Can anyone give examples where the simple infinitive has never existed, apart from being combined with a particle?

The question in your title and question in your body do not match. There is a big difference between the basic verb not existing anymore and never having existed. Please [edit] your question to clarify. Also please ensure that the question body is self-contained and doesn’t require the title.

Listening to the swiss traffic news one encounters the verb "verunfallen", where the noun "Unfall" is any type of car crash or accident, and "Fall" is a fall. That example has even two, "ver" + "un", prefixes, and "unfallen" is apparently never used.

Yes, there are many such words:
nonexistent

etwas verlieren (to lose something)
The word lieren does not exist, but verlieren does.
sich entschuldigen, jemanden beschuldigen (to apologize, to accuse someone)
The word schuldigen does not exist as a verb, only as a form of the adjectiv schuldig (guilty).
(»Die schuldigen Personen sind auf der Flucht.«)
jemanden entlarven (to expose/debunk/unmask someone)
The word larven does not exist, but entlarven does.
etwas vergessen (to forget something)
The word gessen does not exist, but vergessen does.
etwas erledigen (to get something done)
The word ledigen does not exist as a verb, only as a form of the adjective ledig (unmarried).
(»Die ledigen Männer betreten den Raum.«)
etwas (einen Kurs) absolvieren (to complete something (a course))
The word solvieren does not exist, but absolvieren does.

outdated

etwas erkunden (to explore something), etwas bekunden (to declare/express something)
The verb kunden (to anounce) is outdated and no longer actively used.
(»Der Herold kundete des Königs Wort.«)
etwas entfernen (to remove something)
The verb fernen (to be far away) is outdated and no longer actively used.
(»Der Ozean fernt mich von dir.«)

There are many more examples, here are some more. (This list is not complete.)
separable verbs (Wir schotten uns ab, wir freunden uns an, der Himmel klart auf, wir büxen aus, ...)

ab-: ab-platten, ab-schlaffen, ab-schotten, ab-specken, ab-statten, ab-wracken, ab-zweigen,
an-: an-feinden, an-freunden, an-maßen, an-öden,
auf-: auf-bahren, auf-klaren, auf-rauen,
aus-: aus-buchten, aus-büxen, aus-kragen, aus-statten, aus-söhnen,
ein-: ein-buchten, ein-gemeinden, ein-heimsen, ein-tüten,
zu-: zu-müllen

inseparable verbs (Wir behaupten uns, die Züge entgleisen, wir erhitzen etwas, ...)

be-: be-haupten, be-kunden, be-ruhigen, be-seitigen, be-stätigen, be-teiligen, be-treuen,
ent-: ent-behren, ent-gleisen, ent-zweien,
er-: er-dreisten, er-gänzen, er-götzen, er-hitzen, er-matten, er-niedrigen,
miss-: miss-lingen,
ver-: ver-kraften, ver-letzen, ver-nichten, ver-zichten,
zer-: zer-fleischen, zer-mürben,

(Note, that flauen exists as grammatical form of the adjective flau = queasy: »Ich habe einen flauen Magen.« = »I have a queasy stomach.« But you are right, that there is no verb flauen.)

Most of these are formed as (prefix)+(some word)+ "-en", and the meaning is usually clear even if the bare (some word)+ "-en" is not a verb, either because it wouldn't make sense or for historical reasons. English has similar constructions, though I assume German has more. For example "belittle" is a verb while "little" is not. Similarly, "befriend" is a verb while "friend" is not, or at least it wasn't until social media was invented.

From what I gathered on Wiktionary, quite a few of those words come from very old Protogermanic forms, and even then they were already prefix+stem verb, but at the time the stem verb still existed as such, e.g. for abflauen or verlieren.
